# How to use "sann" function in R to solve graph problems?

Tags: r, graphs

I came across a package in R which has a function called `sann` for simulated annealing.

`sann` uses parameters `fn` and `gr` to optimize and to select new points, respectively.

For something like the max-clique or max-stable set problems, `fn` would be a summing function, but it's less clear how one would formulate `gr` to fix these graph computations. In these cases, how would `gr` "select"?

Comment: If you have a specific, reproducible example then that would probably add value. Also, are you sure that you're talking about a *package* in R? I see no package called `sann`. I do see a `sann` function in the `ConsPlan` package...  I'm pretty sure that's what you meant, so I'm going to edit the question. Please let me know if I'm off base.

Comment: Upon further investigation, you actually could've gotten this `sann` function from a few different packages. The definition of `sann` varies between them, based on the developers comments in various R mailing lists. Were you perhaps using the `optim` package?

Answer (score 1):

First, some clarification on terminology.

A *package* in R is a collection of R functions, data, and compiled code in a well-defined format.

SANN (`sann`) is not a package. Depending on which package you're using, `sann` is either a function or, more often, a *method* used within an optimization function.

Packages containing `sann` include `optim`, `trustOptim`, `consPlan`, and `constrOptim`.

In the package `optim`, the `sann` method is implemented as:

```
> func <- function(x){
+   out <- (x[1]-2)^2 + (x[2]-1)^2
+   return <- out
+   }> 
> optim(par=c(0,0), fn=func, gr = NULL,
+       method = c("SANN"),
+       lower = -Inf, upper = Inf,
+       control = list(), hessian = T)
```

As you said, for the "SANN" (`sann`) method `gr` is used to generate a new candidate point. If it is NULL a default Gaussian Markov kernel is used.

Now in your use case -- the case of a graph -- what you probably want to do is to [use `par` and `value` to pass values to `fn` and `gr`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/graphics/par). This is a nice feature of this implementation of SANN in `optim` which is covered a little more than half way  through this [documentation page](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/stats/optim).

`par` is the best set of parameters found and `value` is the value of `fn` corresponding to `par`.